# anyone know how to reset source.list?

Tags: source-packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

is there anyway to reset my source.list  ? i try to follow the trick for this forum http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1219528 but not helping .. what i want is ,, to reinstall the ubuntu 1204 source list. without reinstalling the ubuntu via live cd . and make my os like fresh installing .. anyone can help me ?

thanks

[image]

[image]

> santos@santos:~$ sudo su [sudo] password for santos: 
>   root@santos:/home/santos# grep -r ppa /etc/apt
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf:machine
>   private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/fullcircle-issue-59/ubuntu /etc/apt/auth.conf:machine
>   private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/tiberiumalliances/ubuntu
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf:machine
>   private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/lordofultima/ubuntu
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf:machine
>   private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf:machine
>   private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/plexmediaserver/ubuntu
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf:machine
>   private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/tiberiumalliances/ubuntu
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_fullcircle-issue-59_ubuntu.list.save:deb
>   https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/fullcircle-issue-59/ubuntu precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-wrapper-ppa-precise.list.save:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/skype-wrapper/ppa/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/agmenor-discvur-precise.list.save:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/agmenor/discvur/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hakermania-format-junkie-precise.list.save:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/hakermania/format-junkie/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/achadwick-mypaint-testing-precise.list.save:deb
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/achadwick/mypaint-testing/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/achadwick-mypaint-testing-precise.list.save:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/achadwick/mypaint-testing/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fioan89-slidewall-precise.list.save:deb
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/fioan89/slidewall/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-precise.list.save:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_plexmediaserver_ubuntu.list.save:deb
>   https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/plexmediaserver/ubuntu
>   precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_tiberiumalliances_ubuntu.list.save:deb
>   https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/tiberiumalliances/ubuntu
>   precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/folke-schwinning-personal-precise.list.save:deb
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/folke-schwinning/personal/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brianrobles204-xkcd-browser-precise.list.save:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/brianrobles204/xkcd-browser/ubuntu precise
>   main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/noneed4anick-cuttlefish-precise.list.save:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/noneed4anick/cuttlefish/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_plexmediaserver_ubuntu.list:deb
>   https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/plexmediaserver/ubuntu
>   precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-mozilla-daily-firefox-aurora-precise.list.save:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu
>   precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webapps-preview-precise.list.save:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/webapps/preview/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_tiberiumalliances_ubuntu.list:deb
>   https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/tiberiumalliances/ubuntu
>   precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/myunity-ppa-precise.list.save:deb
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/myunity/ppa/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/luciomrx-switzallnew-precise.list.save:deb
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/luciomrx/switzallnew/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-precise.list.save:deb
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_intellij-idea-ce_ubuntu.list.save:deb
>   https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/intellij-idea-ce/ubuntu
>   precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/george-edison55-nitroshare-precise.list.save:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/nitroshare/ubuntu precise
>   main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_lordofultima_ubuntu.list.save:deb
>   https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/lordofultima/ubuntu
>   precise main #Added by software-center; credentials stored in
>   /etc/apt/auth.conf
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/achadwick-mypaint-testing-precise.list:deb
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/achadwick/mypaint-testing/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/achadwick-mypaint-testing-precise.list:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/achadwick/mypaint-testing/ubuntu precise main
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atareao-atareao-precise.list.save:deb-src
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu precise main
>   root@santos:/home/santos#

Comment: Good eye @gertvdijk.

Comment: @gertvdijk the link you gave not help me .. give me problem .. Fetched 25.7 MB in 7min 35s (56.4 kB/s)                                                                                                          
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/achadwick/mypaint-testing/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/achadwick/mypaint-testing/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @santosamaru The output you just gave indicates that you didn't completely reset it. You still have PPAs installed. See the comments for someone with the exact same issue. (more specifically: see the files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory)

Comment: which i means .. i have following all the step from that link  i will post my source list ss @gertvdijk

Comment: @santosamaru Look at files **inside the directory**. You're opening a directory with your editor! Please provide the output of `grep -r ppa /etc/apt` run from a terminal (please copy/paste text, no need for screenshots!)

Comment: Good grief... you've installed a huge amount of PPAs! To reset it all, you'll have to remove them all... see [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) or the answer provided here using the GUI. Oh and please use the "code sample" formatting next time - the block quote just destroyed it all.

Comment: This was answhered here http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: @gertvdijk emm well that alot .. well if i download live cd .. is there any option to re install via live cd ?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have several ways (Am pretty sure this question is a duplicate but I can't find it):

1. Open the DASH and type `software` you will see one option that says `software sources`

   [image]

   You will see that it will have several tabs that each one adds up to the amount of repository lines in your `sources.list`, for example you have the

   [image]

   and the

   [image]

   and also the

   [image]

   from which you can change in any of this what appears on your source file.
2. Another is to literally edit the file itself. So open a terminal and:

   `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

   and edit away what you do not need. Add a `#` before the line to comment it out. It is better than deleting it, just in case you make a mistake you can go back.

Every time you change this, always do an `sudo apt-get update` to verify that everything is OK. `apt-get` will notify you if there is a problem with one of the repositories (Misspelled, Wrong symbols, etc..)

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question; how do you reset the file.