# How to fix "Failed to download repository information" error while updating?

Tags: apt

How can I fix this? I can't update anything at all.

I've tried to switch to my best server in the options.

When I do `sudo apt-get update`, this is what I get:

> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release  Unable to find
>   expected entry 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong
>   sources.list entry or malformed file) E: Some index files failed to
>   download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.*

When I do `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get this:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

the contents of my source.list:

> deb http://ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ quantal universe restricted main

....update: when I update, it looks for 'universe/binary-1386/Packages'

however, if I go to: ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release with Google Chrome, I see that the file is actually named "universe/binary-i386/Packages" (it's with an i, not a 1) . how can I fix this and make it expect the proper package?

Comment: the 1st output shows you got problems with your `source.list` files. so please Post the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` as for the 2nd output means you don't have more updates in Other words, the command is working fine. and check this Question to know what to post http://askubuntu.com/questions/112988/why-is-apt-get-giving-me-404-not-found-errors

Comment: this is my sources.list, it's pretty barebones:

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ quantal universe restricted main

Comment: open the terminal then type this command: `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` . A new window will show up. Copy everything inside and paste it to your question. Use the edit button in this page so that you can edit your question and insert the copied contents

Comment: I updated the first page, but yeah, the literal only line in my sources.list is:

"deb http://ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ quantal universe restricted main"

Comment: I've also tried to replace my sources.list with a generated one... but it ends up defaulting to that one line

Comment: THis is my `sources.list` file. http://i.imgur.com/TfBBjpH.png Did you see how long is the list? if you only `deb http://ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ quantal universe restricted main` Then you may want to check this link to reset your `sources.list` file http://askubuntu.com/questions/251225/anyone-know-how-to-reset-source-list

Comment: here is my sources.list file screenshot. I was playing with the settings which is why there's a few more lines...

http://i.imgur.com/QePvm3r.png

Comment: Oh I see, then you probably need to reset it. Here is a link that shows you how to reset it http://askubuntu.com/questions/251225/anyone-know-how-to-reset-source-list

Comment: I've already tried resetting my sources.list, it just defaults back to this one..

when I update, it looks for 'universe/binary-1386/Packages'

however, if I go to: http://ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release, I see that the file is actually named "universe/binary-i386/Packages" (it's with an i, not a 1) . how can I fix this and make it expect the proper package?

Comment: I asked for help in the chat but they seem inactive. I gave them the link anyway, they probably can you help you soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you've run `dpkg --add-architecture 1386` at some point. If `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` shows `1386`, running `dpkg --remove-architecture 1386` should fix the problem.

Comment: this worked, thank you so much! now I can finally start installing software.

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled the "ppa" lines in the "Software & Updates" app under the "Other Software" tab. It works fine now. It turns out that when I installed the Razer keyboard software (and google earth), that's when I started getting the error message described above.